# NiFi How to get updated JSON value in UpdateAttribute processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have following workflow:

ConsumeKafkaData->EvaluateJsonFlow->UpdateRecord->Putfile.

I am having following simple JSON message:
{"name":"Yeshwant","active":false}

In EvaluateJsonPath, I created one attribute "name" in configuration which is linked to "name" attribute of above json data.

In UpdateAttribute processor, I created one rule that when value of "name" equals to "dummy" then changed to "funny". I am able to change the value of attribute "name" to value "funny". But the input and output json data did not channge. why? How does UpdateAttribute changes data in JSON directly? is there any configuration I am missing?

Even at PutFile processor I don't see json data changed.

Thanks
Yeshwant

Answer (score 4):

In the existing flow you are changing the value of the **`attribute associated to the flowfile`** not the actual content of the flowfile.

After **UpdateAttribute** processor use **AttributesToJson** processor and recreate your Output **JSON** content.

***Flow:***

```
1. ConsumeKafkaData
2. EvaluateJsonFlow //Extract all json data attributes as flowfile attributes
3. UpdateAttribute 
4. AttributeToJSON //AttributesList -> name,active; Destination -> flowfile Content
5. Putfile
```

For more details/usage of AttributesToJSON processor refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/136128/what-should-be-there-in-attributelist-inside-an-at.html) link.

In addition you can use Record oriented processors for this case i.e. ***`UpdateRecord/QueryRecord`*** processor then use ***LiteralValue*** strategy and use `Expression language` **`if-else`** on the value of `name` attribute.

In case if you are using `QueryRecord processor` then write a case statement in your sql query.

Refer [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/189642/update-the-contents-of-flowfile-by-using-updaterec.html) link for more details/usage updateRecord processor.

Refer [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html) link for more details/usage of QueryRecord processor.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out it today. I am using NiFi version 1.8.0. Does your answer still remains same?

Comment: @YeshwantKAKAD, Yes, the answer remains `same in NiFi-1.8.0` version also.

Comment: Hi Shu, I have an array in json. How can I specify path of an attribute which is inside array? attributes inside nested josn blocks? nested section? Thanks.

Comment: @YeshwantKAKAD, One way would be using `EvaluateJson` processor and keep 
 matching `json path` to extract values of the attribute (or) 2. by using `JsonPathReader` controller service we can add json path properties then controller will extract the values. (or) 3.Flatten all the nested data using `JoltTransform*`/`FlattenRecord` processors then use `EvaluateJsonPath` processor. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/147362/jolttransformjson-spec.html